# Como o Symfony 2 gerencia conflitos de rotas com o mesmo name

Tags: symfony-2

Estou a utilizar annotations no projeto.

No arquivo `routing.yml` tenho a seguinte configuração:

```
acme_store:
    resource: "@AcmeStoreBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /acme

teste_blog:
    resource: "@TesteBlogBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
```

Repare que no bundle `AcmeStore` estou a utilizar o prefixo `acme`.

Na classe controladora `DefaultController.php` do bundle `AcmeStore`, tenho a seguinte rota configurada:

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="index")
 */
public function indexAction()
{
    return $this->render('AcmeStoreBundle:Default:index.html.twig');
}
```

Na classe controladora `DefaultController.php` do bundle `TesteBlog`, tenho a seguinte rota configurada:

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="index")
 */
public function indexAction()
{
    return $this->render('TesteBlogBundle:Default:index.html.twig');
}
```

Repare que a propriedade `name` é igual nos 2 controladores.

Na console, ao executar o comando `php app/console debug:router` é retornado o seguinte resultado:

```
------- ------- ------- ----- -----
Name    Method  Scheme  Host  Path                               
------- ------- ------- ----- -----
index   ANY     ANY     ANY   /
```

Não deveria existir mais uma linha?

```
------- ------- ------- ----- -----
Name    Method  Scheme  Host  Path                               
------- ------- ------- ----- -----
index   ANY     ANY     ANY   / 
index   ANY     ANY     ANY   /acme
```

Se mesmo utilizando um prefixo não podemos utilizar o mesmo `name` para diferentes rotas, quais são as boas práticas quando escolhemos um nome para a rota?

Pergunto isso porque é possível instalar bundles de terceiros e isso pode gerar conflitos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não deve ter o mesmo nome para indicar rotas diferentes!(assim como não existe um mesmo cpf para identificar pessoas diferentes)
Digo diferente pois se fossem iguais não faria sentido ter duas, existe algo difere entre elas.

A respeito das boas pratica você pode seguir o exemplo do fosUserBundle que utiliza o nome do bundle sempre em suas rotas. EX: fos_user_change_password.

No seu caso ficaria teste_index e acme_index.

[How to Match a Route Based on the Host](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/hostname_pattern.html)

Answer (score 1):

Quando nomeio as rotas para a minha aplicação, costumo usar a seguinte metodologia:

```
{bundle}_{controller}_{action}
```

No entanto, você tem a opção de deixar o nome vazio. Dessa forma, o framework determina o nome da rota automaticamente. Daí é só ver os nomes das rotas no comando `app/console router:debug` (no caso de Symfony <= 2.8) ou `bin/console debug:router` (no caso de Symfony >= 3.0).

Comment: Olá Rodrigo, obrigado! Entretanto preciso dar um "name" porque estou a utilizar annotations. Mas utilizar o nome da bundle como você postou, já resolve problemas de conflitos.

Comment: Então, mas como eu disse, você pode deixar o framework gerar os nomes e depois ver os nomes no comando acima para usá-los na aplicação. :)

Comment: Ah ok, entendi.